# Title field in admin

Tags: django

I have a model:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    link = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    book_id = models.IntegerField()
    review_id = models.IntegerField()
    content = models.TextField()
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
```

If I open admin http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/my_app/review/ I'll see the list of records. For each record Django Admin display only one field ('Name' in my case).  How Django Admin choise the field to display in the list of records.

Firstly I thinked that it is a first field in my model. I have moved Name-field down in the field list and recreate the database, but there was nothing to change.

Comment: When you say you did recreate the database, do you mean only calling syncdb again after moving the field name ?

Comment: I have deleted database file and called syncdb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django calls the `__unicode__` method on the model. For configuring the displayed fields in the change list see the [detailed documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)!